# Why doesn't the while loop end?

Tags: python, while-loop

This is the code I am trying to run...

```
scoreCount = int(input("How many scores do you want to record?"))
recordedValues = 0
averageScore = totalScore/scoreCount
highestScore = 0
totalScore = 0
```

## This is where I believe the code stops working...

```
while recordedValues <= scoreCount:
    score = int(input("\n\nEnter Score,:")
    if type(score)== int:
                totalScore == totalScore + score
                recordedValues == recordedValues + 1
    if score >= highestScore:
                highestScore = score
    else:
                print("\n\nThe scores are not integer values")
                quit()
```

How can I get the while loop to end and have the average score/highest score/recorded values displayed?

## Edit: Thanks for the help, I have solved the problem.

Comment: `recordedValues == recordedValues + 1` does not alter `recordedValues`. You mean `=`, not `==`

Comment: You already cast input to an int.. why do you need to check if `type(score) == int`?

Comment: Also the "else" block inside the while loop should be after the first "if" block. But yeah you are already casting to int so why are you checking for int?

Answer (score 2):

You put == instead of = inside the while loop:

```
if type(score)== int:
    totalScore == totalScore + score
    recordedValues == recordedValues + 1
```

so 'recordedValues' and 'totalScore' not changed.

Edit: '[khelwood](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3890632/khelwood)' already mention it in the comments.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what was already mentioned in the comments. And what new details are you adding here?

Comment: Sorry, I wrote at the same time.

Comment: in my opinion comments should not give the answer so if someone use the infos from the comments to create a good looking answer its a good job. otherwise every user have to analysis all comments to determine the answer

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few issues with your code: You try to assign `averageScore` to `totalScore/scoreCount` before `totalScore` is even defined, you sometimes use the `==` equality checker as an assignment operator, you check that `score` is in `int` even though it is already converted, and there are issues with the conditionals in your while loop. Here is what you can do:

Replace repetitive type testing with exception handling and remove the illegal variable assignment:

```
try:
    scoreCount = int(input("How many scores do you want to record?"))
except ValueError:
    print("\n\nYou need to enter an integer...")
    quit()
recordedValues = 0
highestScore = 0
totalScore = 0
```

Change `>=` to `>` for the highest score, fix the variable assignments, and replace unneeded type checking with exception handling.

```
while recordedValues <= scoreCount:
    try:
        score = int(input("\n\nEnter Score: "))
    except ValueError:
        print('Scores must be numbers.')
        quit()
    totalScore += score
    recordedValues += 1
    if score > highestScore:
        highestScore = score

print("\n\nThe amount of values recorded:", recordedValues)
print("\n\nThe average score:", totalScore / scoreCount)
print("\n\nThe highest score:", highestScore)
```